# function to calculate and plot surface

Tags: python, surface

I have a panel, 3-dimension data table. It's like a grid, just points(x,y,z).

I want to input two of them, then return the other one number, like inputting x and y, return z. But the x, y may not just exist in the grip points, so it needs to calculate by linear or any method.

In addition, I want to plot as a surface.

I googled and found the numpy.meshgrid(), I am confused how to use it. Or could you recommend any package or function could do this task?

Thank you so much !

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) from the matrplotlib docs. You should find examples for surface plots there.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it is clear and great! So thank you. Do you have any idea could calculate and return by inputting two of parameters?

Comment: On the part about inputting `x` and `y` to get `z` as output: You could define a function with `def f(xx,yy)` that is able to take NumPy arrays. If your table of `n` 3-tuples `(x,y,z)` then is an NumPy array of shape `(n, 3)`, i.e. `x, y, z` are the first, second, third column, then you can call `f(x[:, 0], y[:, 0])` to get all `n` `z`-values with one function call.

Comment: @Michael Okay. Thank you so much!